# Parallel sapply into a for loop

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I would like to know how to use the parallel version of `sapply` into a `for` loop in R.
The following code is a trivial example of what I would like to do (for each sample size, I get as output 5 times the sum of sample_size+5):

```
#Non-parallel
n <- c(10,25,30)
out <- c()
for(i in 1:length(n))
    out[i] <- sum(sapply(1:5, function(j) n[i]+5))

#Parallel
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
n <- c(10,25,30)
out <- c()
for(i in 1:length(n))
    out[i] <- sum(parSapply(cl, 1:5, function(j) n[i]+5))
```

The non-parallel version works, whilst for the parallel I get the error message "cannot find object i".

Comment: You don't pass `i` to the workers. Make it a parameter of your function: `parSapply(cl, 1:5, function(j, i) n[i]+5, i = i)`. *However*, if you want efficiency, usually you shouldn't parallelize the inner loop, but the outer loop.

Comment: Great, it works now. For the task I'm doing (not the trivial example I wrote before) I think it's more efficient to parallelize the inner loop, since the outer loop runs through 100 sample sizes whereas the inner loop runs 50000 replication of a function for each sample size.

Comment: Just tried to parallelize the outer loop: the computation time is longer than parallelizing the inner loop.